# Use tested machine learning model on new unlabeled single observation or dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r-caret

How can I use a trained and tested algorithm (eg. machine learning classifier) after being saved, on a new observation/dataset, whose I do not know the class (eg. ill vs healthy) based on predictors used for model training?
I use caret but can't find any lines of code for this.
many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After training and testing any machine learning model you can save the model as `.rds` file and call it as

```
#Save the fitted model as .rds file
saveRDS(model_fit, "model.rds")
my_model <- readRDS("model.rds")
```

Creating a new observation from the same dataset or you can use a new dataset also

```
new_obs <- iris[100,] #I am using default iris dataset, 100 no sample
```

Prediction on the new observation

```
predicted_new <- predict(my_model, new_obs)
confusionMatrix(reference = new_obs$Species, data = predicted_new)
table(new_obs$Species, predicted_new)
```

Comment: Many thanks! What about if I have transformed (e.g. normalization) my training set? How can I deal with the fact that my new observation (or observations if a dataset) is a raw score?

Comment: You have to normalize the new observation first then use the predict function with normalized data.

Comment: So should I normalize it with min and max of the trained dataset?

Comment: Better you should use `scale` and `center` function of R. Though I have not used these for single observation.